# extjs shrink area between displayfields (labels and values)

Tags: css, extjs

how do I shrink the area between these displayfields?
I've tried moving padding... margins... nothing seems to work.  When I do end up getting the labels the way they should look (with very little space)... then the values are not aligned next to the label correctly.

[image]

this is how I have it setup.

```
                            layout: 'column',
                        defaults: {
                            layout: 'form',
                            xtype: 'container',
                            //defaultType: 'textfield',
                            style: 'width: 50%'
                        },
                        items: [{
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Client',
                                    bind: {
                                        value: '{selectedClientListModel.ClientName}'
                                    },
                                    fieldStyle: 'color: #ff0000; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;',
                                    labelStyle: 'color: #ff0000; padding: 0px; margin: -5px;'
                                    //ui: 'dark'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Acct Desc',
                                    itemId: 'textfieldAcctDesc',
                                    bind: {
                                        value: '{selectedManager.AcctShortCode}'
                                    },
                                    fieldStyle: 'color: #ff0000; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;',
                                    labelStyle: 'color: #ff0000; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; margin: -15px;'
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Acct Num',
                                    itemId: 'textfieldAcctNum',
                                    bind: {
                                        value: '{selectedManager.AcctNum}'
                                    },
                                    fieldStyle: 'color: #ff0000; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;',
                                    labelStyle: 'color: #ff0000; line-height: 1; padding: 0px; margin: -5px;'
                                }
                            ]
                        }, {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`displayfields` are intended to align neatly with other form fields - which have spacious borders around their input fields. For that reason, [`displayfields` have the same height, they even haven't got a different SCSS variable for `displayfield` height](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Display-css_var-S-form-field-height).

Furthermore, from the CSS classes available, the fieldLabel cannot distinguish between being a displayfield's label and another field's label. Because of that, you will have to give your displayfield at least a custom `userCls`, or else all your regular form fields will look ridiculous.

Then you can go and add some CSS like this:

```
.myUserCls,
.myUserCls .x-form-item-label,
.myUserCls .x-form-display-field
 { 
    line-height:16px; 
    min-height:16px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
 }
```

[I have made you a fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bmr)